# How to pass partitionKey or MessageId when you publish to topic in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, azure

I have service bus topic with `Partitioning` and `Duplicate detection` enabled. I am following [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions?tabs=connection-string#send-messages-to-a-topic) approach to publish to the topic.

[image]

While sending the messages in batch, I am getting following error.

> Error occurred:  ServiceBusError: InvalidOperationError: Message to a partitioned entity with duplicate detection enabled must have either PartitionKey or MessageId

**Question:**

How to pass `PartitionKey or MessageId` in my node app? I am using `@azure/service-bus"` package.

**Code:**

```
const { ServiceBusClient } = require("@azure/service-bus");

const connectionString = "<SERVICE BUS NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING>"
const topicName = "<TOPIC NAME>";

const messages = [
    { body: "Albert Einstein" },
    { body: "Werner Heisenberg" },
    { body: "Marie Curie" },
    { body: "Steven Hawking" },
    { body: "Isaac Newton" },
    { body: "Niels Bohr" },
    { body: "Michael Faraday" },
    { body: "Galileo Galilei" },
    { body: "Johannes Kepler" },
    { body: "Nikolaus Kopernikus" }
 ];

 async function main() {
    // create a Service Bus client using the connection string to the Service Bus namespace
    const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

    // createSender() can also be used to create a sender for a queue.
    const sender = sbClient.createSender(topicName);

    try {
        // Tries to send all messages in a single batch.
        // Will fail if the messages cannot fit in a batch.
        // await sender.sendMessages(messages);

        // create a batch object
        let batch = await sender.createMessageBatch(); 
        for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            // for each message in the arry         

            // try to add the message to the batch
            if (!batch.tryAddMessage(messages[i])) {            
                // if it fails to add the message to the current batch
                // send the current batch as it is full
                await sender.sendMessages(batch);

                // then, create a new batch 
                batch = await sender.createMessageBatch();

                // now, add the message failed to be added to the previous batch to this batch
                if (!batch.tryAddMessage(messages[i])) {
                    // if it still can't be added to the batch, the message is probably too big to fit in a batch
                    throw new Error("Message too big to fit in a batch");
                }
            }
        }

        // Send the last created batch of messages to the topic
        await sender.sendMessages(batch);

        console.log(`Sent a batch of messages to the topic: ${topicName}`);

        // Close the sender
        await sender.close();
    } finally {
        await sbClient.close();
    }
}

// call the main function
main().catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error occurred: ", err);
    process.exit(1);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to pass PartitionKey or MessageId in my node app?

You just need to specify the message id in `messageId` property and partition key in `partitionKey` property of the message. For example, your payload would look something like:

```
const messages = [
    { body: "Albert Einstein", messageId: 'message-id', partitionKey: 'partition-key' },
    { body: "Werner Heisenberg", messageId: 'message-id', partitionKey: 'partition-key' },
    { body: "Marie Curie", messageId: 'message-id', partitionKey: 'partition-key' },
    { body: "Steven Hawking", messageId: 'message-id', partitionKey: 'partition-key' },
    { body: "Isaac Newton", messageId: 'message-id', partitionKey: 'partition-key' },
    { body: "Niels Bohr", messageId: 'message-id', partitionKey: 'partition-key' },
    { body: "Michael Faraday", messageId: 'message-id', partitionKey: 'partition-key' },
    { body: "Galileo Galilei", messageId: 'message-id', partitionKey: 'partition-key' },
    { body: "Johannes Kepler", messageId: 'message-id', partitionKey: 'partition-key' },
    { body: "Nikolaus Kopernikus", messageId: 'message-id', partitionKey: 'partition-key' }
 ];
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusmessage?view=azure-node-latest